# don't show zero ("0") in datagridview cell in c#

Tags: string, datagridview, format

I used string.format() for a column in datagridview to separate thousands with comma but

in cases that the value is zero "0" the datagridview's cell don't show  zero and cell is empty

dataGridView2.Columns[7].ValueType = typeof(string);

dataGridView2.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.Format = string.Format("#,#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;

please help me

regards

Comment: I wonder, are the values null, instead of 0?

Comment: no value is "0" but because of string format cell is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN:Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

- # Never displays zero if it is not a significant digit.
- 0 means a digit and display 0 if nothing is present.

So I changed the expression to `#,0`, and it worked:

- 0.0 => 0
- 50.0 => 50
- 74.0 => 74
- 1260.0 => 1,260
- 12325.0 => 12,325